How to change facet top visible value 6 to 5 in the composable storefront
Currently in search list page Facet showing 6 value is visible I want to change it 6 to 5. How to configure the default value in composable storefront.
DEFAULT_TOP_VALUES

Need to change value the default value. There is no configuration in Backoffice. Can we control through impex or we have the OOTB service for change default visible value.

This is an injectable class , did u try defining custom normalizer & define as custom injection
